# open a file in c++ from desktop using winapi

Tags: c++, file, winapi, message

I've made a program that can edit and open .BMP files, but you can only open these files from within the program.

if i open the file with the program by clicking on the file and selecting my own program, it just opens my program and does nothing.

how do I open a file in this way, or which message do I have to process.

Comment: Isn't the file name passed to the argv[] argument of main?

Comment: @Zeta: Pretty much, except the question is tagged `winapi`, so he probably has `WinMain` rather than `main`.

Comment: Odd that an answer comes from an account that was created within seconds of the question being asked.... Both accounts were also within ~10 minutes of each other.

Answer (score 4):

By default (meaning your program didn't install registry entries requesting DDE associations), the filename will be passed on the command line.  You can use the [`GetCommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx) function to retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

When you open .bmp-file by "Open with..." context menu item, your programm is called with command-line parameter that is equal to file name.

Therefore you should parse your command line parameters